# $ operator for variable object names

Tags: r

I am trying to use the $ operator for selecting and reformating specific columns  in a for loop on variably created data.frame objects. I tried 4 different solutions in my commented code, but none of them works. I looked all over SO but i don't seem to find another solution to try. 
How can i make use of the $ operator to select specific columns with variable data.frame names?

Thanks

```
weather_data_files<-c("CMC","ECMWF","ECMWF_VAR_EPS_MONTHLY_FORECAST",
                          "GFS","ICON_EU","UKMET_EURO4")
for(filename in weather_data_files){

  #create data frame environment objects
  assign(paste(filename),read.csv(file = paste(filename,".csv",sep = ""),sep = ";"))

  #first solution does not work, because filename is here an atomic vector 
  #rather than a data.frame
  #ErrorMessage: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
  filename$Forecast.Time<- as.POSIXct(filename$Forecast.Time,
                                      format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M+%S",tz="UTC")

  #ok get it, let's try second soltution,but
  #it also does not work allthough i try to get the data.frame object
  #ErrorMesssage: could not find function "get<-
  get(filename)$Forecast.Time<-
    as.POSIXct(get(filename)$Forecast.Time,format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M+%S",tz="UTC")

  #Third solution as.name also does not work
  #ErrorMessage: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
  as.name(filename)$Forecast.Time<-
    as.POSIXct(as.name(filename)$Forecast.Time,format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M+%S",tz="UTC")

  #Fourth solution comparable to second solution, still not working
  #ErrorMessage: could not find function "eval<-"
  eval(assign(filename,get(filename)))$Forecast.Time<-
    as.POSIXct(eval(assign(filename,get(filename)))$Forecast.Time,
                format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M+%S",tz="UTC")

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `get(filename)[,colname]`?

Comment: can you give a sample of your data files, `CMC.csv` for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem is you're passing in character strings, not objects. The `get` function retrieves the object, just doesn't have a place to store it.

You could always load the character string into a temporary variable as you're looping. Operate on the temporary variable and then assign when you're done.

```
for(filename in c("a","b")){
    tmp <- get(filename)
}
```

You could also skip most of the for loop and use the `apply` family.

```
files = lapply(paste(c("CMC","ECMWF","ECMWF_VAR_EPS_MONTHLY_FORECAST",
                      "GFS","ICON_EU","UKMET_EURO4"),".csv",sep=""),
       read.csv,sep=";")
files = lapply(files,function(x){x$Forecast.Time = as.POSIXct(x$Forecast.Time,
               format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M+%S",tz="UTC");return(x)}
```

Now you have a list of your files you can work on. You could assign them to global variables if you want.